# Mongo is pending on password despit the --password option

Tags: mongodb, ansible

## Context

- **Mongod version v3.2.11**
- **MongoDB shell version: 3.2.11**
- **Debian stretch**
- **ppc64** architecture
- **Ansible 2.7.6**

## Issue

I am executing a mongo command through **ansible** using mongo shell.
Here is the lines i use in my task :

```
   - name: Add the shard to the mongos
      shell: /usr/bin/mongo localhost:{{ mongos_port }}/admin -u admin -p {{ mongo_admin_password }} /tmp/shard_init.js
      delegate_to: '{{ item }}'
      with_items: "{{ groups['mongos_servers'] }}"
```

But the command is pending at :

`TASK [Add the shard to the mongos] ************************************************`

When i execute the command line on the remote machine, despite the `-p` option set, it still asks me to enter the password ...

```
$ /usr/bin/mongo localhost:2700/admin -u admin -p "XXXX" /tmp/shard_init.js
MongoDB shell version: 3.2.11
Enter password:
```

It there a way to execute a **mongo** command through **ansible** on a database that reaquires authentication ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with the mysql CLI method :

```
/usr/bin/mongo localhost:2700/admin -u admin -pXXXX /tmp/shard_init.js
```

Where the password is just near the -p option.
Like the usage option show this isn't the right way to do but in this case the command seems to work.